# Allowing user to change the Vcl theme of the project during run time

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10-seattle

I am currently working on Delphi 10 Seattle and I was wondering if/how it is possible to allow a user to change the theme of the program through potentially a list box

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: In addition to the linked post, there are examples of doing this in the sample apps installed for Seattle, particularly the one for the new SplitView component (in the Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\SplitView folder).

Comment: yes, but do not change theme if you are displaying Modal window.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606625/delphi-xe7-dx10-using-tstylemanager-trysetstyle-in-runtime-when-modal-window-d